# How can i detect if an item in a listbox have been selected more then once?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this event code of the listBox:

```
I tried ot do it this way and it's almost working good.


private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {




            if (recentItems.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                itemExist = true;
                item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                this.f1.PlayLightnings();
                f1.pdftoolsmenu();
            }
            else
            {
                itemExist = false;
                item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                recentItems.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                this.f1.PlayLightnings();
                f1.pdftoolsmenu();
            }


        }
```

Im using a new bool variable itemExist and check and if the List recentItems wich is  don't contain the selectedItem add it.

And if it does exist set the flag to true.

Then in the other code in Form1 im doing:

```
if (Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Mode.itemExist == true)
                {
                    if (!pdf1.Lightnings.Contains(Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Mode.item))
                    {
                        pdf1.Lightnings.Add(Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Mode.item);
                    }
                }
```

So it's working as i wanted but the problem is that each new item i select in the listBox click on it i have to click on it twice since first time it's not in the recentItems and only on the second click it does in the recentItems and only on the second click it's changing the flag to true.

So how can i solve this problem in the SelectedIndexChanged event ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to store list of items selected then, not just the last one. Use `List<string> recentItems = new List<string>();` then instead of `item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` have `recentItems.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());` after checking when it was last selected..

Comment: I just changed/edited my question i solved it but having a small problem.

Comment: Tried that code and it's working, I can add item with one click, no more needed.

Answer (score 0):

I saw now i don't need the code part in Form1 only this code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            this.f1.PlayLightnings();
            f1.pdftoolsmenu();
            if (item != null && !pdf1.Lightnings.Contains(item.ToString()))
            {
                pdf1.Lightnings.Add(item.ToString());             
            }
        }
```